# How can I use the WooCommerce pagination function on the my account orders page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to replace the default pagination from WooCommerce on the MyAccount -> Orders page. The pagination shows up but I've currently the problem, that the links getting wrong page numbers. So for example when I'm on page 2, all other links are pointing to page too but it must be (1) for page 1 with the link to this page an so on:

```
<?php if ( 1 < $customer_orders->max_num_pages ) : ?>
    <nav class="page-pagination">
        <?php
        $base = esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders', $current_page ) );
        echo paginate_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pagination_args', array(
            'base'      => $base,
            'format'    => '',
            'add_args'  => false,
            'current'   => max( 1, $current_page ?? wc_get_loop_prop( 'current_page' ) ),
            'total'     => $customer_orders->max_num_pages,
            'prev_text' => '&larr;',
            'next_text' => '&rarr;',
            'type'      => 'list',
            'end_size'  => 3,
            'mid_size'  => 3,
        ) ) );
        ?>
    </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Maybe you have any idea how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. Maybe it's helping you some day:

```
<?php if ( 1 < $customer_orders->max_num_pages ) : ?>
    <nav class="page-pagination">
        <?php
        $base = esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders' ) );
        echo paginate_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pagination_args', array(
            'base'      => $base . '%_%',
            'format'    => '%#%/',
            'add_args'  => false,
            'current'   => max( 1, $current_page ),
            'total'     => $customer_orders->max_num_pages,
            'prev_text' => '&larr;',
            'next_text' => '&rarr;',
            'type'      => 'list',
            'end_size'  => 3,
            'mid_size'  => 3,
        ) ) );
        ?>
    </nav>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem was the base and the format. I've left them empty because I was sure that I don't need this (which is stupid). So this is a working example which you can place under your orders table to show the WC paginator here.